# Bar Graph in Python with 2 scales (y-axis) with matplotlib import

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph

So I'm coding a bar graph that has the predicted total profit, actual total profit, and percent error calculations from elsewhere in the same program. With this graph I'm trying to make a second y-axis so that the left-hand side caps at 50000 and the right-hand side caps at 100: this being for the profits and percent error respectively. I believe I've accomplished this for the most part, save for the fact that the bars only respond to 1 of the scales, but never both. How do I get the 3 bars to correlate to the correct scales (2 for left-hand, 1 for right-hand)? Also, ignore the fact that the code is different in the image than what I posted, as well as the fact that the second axis is incorrect. I fixed that with the code that I posted, I only need what I've asked for. Code and output:

```
    # Create a bar graph
objects = ('Pre_Total_Profit', 'Act_Total_Profit', 'Percent_Error')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [tpp, tp, pe]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()                                 # Apply subplots to x-axis (for 2 y axis)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()                                       # Create second y-axis
ax1.set_ylabel('Dollars', color='g')        # Label y-axis in green
ax2.set_ylabel('Percent', color='m')           # Label second y-axis in magenta
ax1.set_ylim([0, 50000])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 100])

plt.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='g')
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.title('Total Profits and Percent Error')

plt.show()
```

To Clarify: The left 2 graphs ("Pre_Total_Profit" and "Act_Total_Profit") should be filled up to the red that I've drawn in, but no more, as it refers only to the left-hand axis ("Dollars"). The right graph ("Percent_Error"), should be 84, referring only to the right-hand axis. This information was taken earlier in the program and placed into a texttable, of which I've linked a portion of for the 3 values I'm interested in. If there's any way I can make myself clearer, please do tell.
[Current Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UijWG.png)

[Desired Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vtAa6.png)

[Reference Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ysq2R.png)

Comment: Instead of `plt.bar()` do `ax1.bar()` for the left two bars and `ax2.bar()` for the right bar.

Comment: @ThomasKühn
So I'm attaching the updated code/output. It's really close but still not what I want. There's excess on the left two bars: https://imgur.com/a/UquFISN

Comment: @Strom I've updated it, as well as an updated image in the comment above, if you think you can help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I figured out my problem and it was very simple. I'm still learning so I didn't realize that performance was for the shape of the bars on the graph, unless I'm still wrong about that. Either way, the fix was adding a second performance variable (performance2) and filling it with dimensions so that it would only create the right-most bar (percent error). This is the code and output if anybody is interested in it, or if anybody needs it.

```
  # Create a bar graph
objects = ('Pre_Total_Profit', 'Act_Total_Profit', 'Percent_Error')
y_pos = np.arange(len(objects))
performance = [tpp, tp, pe]
performance2 = [0, 0, pe]
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots()                                 # Apply subplots to x-axis (for 2 y axis)
ax2 = ax1.twinx()                                       # Create second y-axis
ax1.set_ylabel('Dollars', color='g')        # Label y-axis in green
ax2.set_ylabel('Percent', color='m')           # Label second y-axis in magenta
ax1.set_ylim([0, (tpp+tp)])
ax2.set_ylim([0, 100])
# When graph shows, ignore the excess cyan on the left 2 bars.
ax1.bar(y_pos, performance, align='center', color='g')  # Left 2 bars (Pre/Act Profits) will show in green/centered
ax2.bar(y_pos, performance2, align='center', alpha=0.5, color='c')  # Right bar (%error) will show in cyan/centered
plt.xticks(y_pos, objects)
plt.title('Total Profits and Percent Error')

plt.show()
```

If anybody is interested in the full code, please do ask. It was a much larger program than just this portion, but this was the part that I had an issue on. Thanks for those that commented and gave me an idea.

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ll4XK.png)